# Prove the following statements about the positive integer n with decimal expansion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, decimal-expansion

(a)n ≡ Σ ak (mod 3)  (view the image)

(b) n ≡ a1a0 (mod 4)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Ogw.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: Are the $a_i$ the decimal expansion of $n$? More precisely, is $n = a_0a_1\dots a_m$?

Comment: yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 0):

For the first exercise, note that if the decimal expansion of n = $a_ma_{m-1}\ldots a_1a_0$, then
$$
n = \sum_{k=0}^ma_k10^k
$$
Also recall that 1 $\equiv 10^k$(mod 3) for every k.
So
$$n (mod 3) \equiv \sum_{k=0}^ma_k10^k(mod 3) \equiv\sum_{k=0}^ma_k(mod 3).\checkmark
$$

Similarly for the second exercise note that 0 $\equiv 10^k$ for k $\ge$2.
So
$$n(mod 4) \equiv \sum_{k=0}^ma_k10^k(mod 4)\equiv\sum_{k=0}^1a_k10^k(mod 4) \equiv a_1a_0(mod4). \checkmark
$$

Comment: thank you so much!